# Form submission using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Form is not submit using ajax.form submit on click li. Give me some solution

My js code is here

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#sortable li').click(function() {

$("#frmgallery").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    alert(formdata);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gallery.php",
        data: formdata,
        success: function(){alert('success');}
    });
});

});
```

HTML is here

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmgallery" name="gallery" action="<?php get_template_directory();?>admin.php?page=gallery/gallery.php">

<ul id="sortable">

Query

<li  class="ui-state-default" name='liindex' id="<?php echo $row['glryRecordId'];?>" >
<span style="display:none"><?php echo $row['glryRecordId'];?></span>
<img class='thumbnail' alt=''  src='<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-content/themes/townsley/upload/<?php echo $row['glryName']; ?>' width='80' height='60' 
 style="border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;padding:2px;"/><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['glryRecordId'];?>" name="recordId[]" />
    <a href="<?php get_template_directory();?>admin.php?page=gallery/gallery.php&delid=<?php echo $row['glryRecordId'];?>" style="display:block;text-align:center"  title="DELETE this image from the record" class="arial-red">Remove</a>
</li>


</ul>
</form>
```

Please help me
Thanks

ajax jquery javascript

Comment: what is `#sortable li` ?. you need to show your html.

Comment: careful with `function(event)`, prefer using a not reserved name like `function(e)`

Comment: Please format your HTML so it is better readable. This will also help yourself. Also, clean-up or remove redundant css classes. I can't imagine your `ul` needs to be sortable (or choose more "semantic" names). From the code it seems you first have to click the `ul#sortable` before you attach the `submit` event-handler, is that on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You should provide your HTML too in your question, but as far as i can see, you have `event` in `event` callbacks with actually nothing to initiate the `submit` event. So basically you should consider something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sortable li').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $("#frmgallery").serialize();
        alert(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gallery.php",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(){alert('success');}
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit functions from [Ajax Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) or the jQuery serialize function.

**Example:**

```
$("#frmgallery").ajaxForm({url: 'gallery.php', type: 'post'})
```

or

```
$("#frmgallery").ajaxSubmit({url: 'gallery.php', type: 'post'})
```

`ajaxForm` will send when the submit button is pressed. `ajaxSubmit` sends immediately.

Comment: I m not using submit button . Form submit when click on li

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried return false at the end of your submit function?

```
    $("#frmgallery").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $(this).serialize();
        alert(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gallery.php",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(){alert('success');}
            error: function(){alert('error');}
        });
        return false;
    });
$('#sortable li').click(function() {

     $("#frmgallery").submit();
});
```

Also post what you get from `$.ajax`call

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#frmgallery").ajaxForm({url: 'gallery.php', type: 'post'})
```

Have you tried return false at the end of your submit function?

```
    $("#frmgallery").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $(this).serialize();
        alert(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gallery.php",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(){alert('success');}
            error: function(){alert('error');}
        });
        return false;
    });
$('#sortable li').click(function() {

     $("#frmgallery").submit();
});
```