# Form submit without going to the target page

Tags: javascript, php, oracle

I have question regarding form submit. I have this simple form on *processFabrication.php* to submit all the variables then process it to the database in another page called *processExceededQty.php*

Co, in *processFabrication.php*, I have

```
 echo "<form action='processExceededQty.php' method='post'>";
```

When I click `submit` it goes to the *processExceededQty.php*.

What I am aiming to do is,

1. When user click submit, display confirmation yes/no with popup
2. After user click yes with the confirmation window, stay in *processFabrication.php* but methods in *processExceededQty.php* is still executed.
3. When user click no on the popup, go back and don't do form action

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: learn about ajax. also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808440/form-submission-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Can you use jQuery? jQuery makes it easy with .preventDefault() and $.post ajax

Comment: this has nothing to do with ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this in your `javascript`:

```
function doSubmit(){

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) {
    // yes
    return true;
} else {
    // Do nothing!
    return false
}
}
```

add the `onsubmit` to your form in `html`:

```
<form action='processExceededQty.php' method='post' onsubmit='doSumit()'>
```

Comment: it works like charm but how do I stay withour redirecting to the process page ?

Comment: @Chriskonz..You can submit the form to the form page itself without passing values to another page. Otherwise you can pass values to another page and after it, redirecting back to the form page

Comment: if you want to sumbit values and not leave the page you need xmlhttp request, this example will allow the submit to pass by return true and stop it by return false

Comment: you have to use AJAX to submit data without returning on action page.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp  will explain how to submit without leaving the page

Answer (score 2):

Addition to @N0M3 answer.
Include below script in your `<head>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and slight change in your function

```
function doSubmit(){

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) {
    // yes
     $(this).submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'processExceededQty.php',
        data : {'username':username}, // where first 'username' is your field name, and second one is your field's value
        method: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
             // data is variable which has return data from `processExceededQty.php` 
             // do whatever you want with data
        }
    });    


} else {
    // Do nothing!
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: dont you need to add return false or the page will submit?

Comment: @N0M3 thx for pointing that, updated my answer. Here `return false` won't work

Answer (score 0):

Use function on the "onsubmit" of the form like below,

```
<form action='processExceededQty.php' method='post' onsubmit='reutrn show_pop_up()'>
```

And on script you ca write following

```
<script>
   function show_pop_up()
   {
      // show pop up
      if(op_up_return =="Yes")
          return true;
      else
          return false;
   }
</script>
```

Hope this will help.